# Can't seem to save the output of a client.shell() command to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, adb, node-webkit, node-modules

I am using node-webkit and ADBkit to attempt to read a line from an android build.prop and do something depending on what that line is.

full script at http://pastebin.com/7N7t1akk

The gist of it is this:

```
var model = client.shell(devices, "su -c 'grep ro.product.model /system/build.prop'" );  
alert(model)
```

i want to read `ro.product.model` from build.prop into the variable `model`
As a test im simply attempting to create an `alert` that displays the return of this shell command, in my case `ro.product.model=KFSOWI` but whenever i run this script with a connected device the `alert` returns `object Object`

edit** 
Ive just realized that `client.getProperties(serial[, callback])` would probably work better but dont understand these functions (specifically callback) very well

I am very new to this area of Javascripting and home someone can offer some insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous programming language, it is built on callbacks. Every function should have callback with data passed to it, if you will watch on [documentation](https://github.com/CyberAgent/adbkit#clientshellserial-command-callback), you have `client.shell(serial, command[, callback])` so data from executing `client.shell()` will be passed to `callback`. You should assign some function that will process callback, for your case will be this

```
client.shell(devices, "su -c 'grep ro.product.model /system/build.prop'", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

P.S. there is no `alert` in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can catch the output in the 2nd argument of client.shell()'s callback:

```
client.shell(devices, "su -c 'grep ro.product.model /system/build.prop'", function(err, output) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `async` / `await` for clearer code.

```
const data = await client.shell(devices, "su -c 'grep ro.product.model /system/build.prop'" );

console.log(data); // => "Samsung.TM395"
```

*Of course, this only will work if this code is in an `async` function.*

#### Streamed data.

For streamed data with adbkit, you will need to do a little more to read the entire stream and then output the results, like so:

```
const stream = await adbClient.shell( config.udid, "ime list -s" ) // adb command to list possible input devices (e.g. keyboards, etc.).
const result = await adb.util.readAll( stream );
console.log( result.toString() ); // => com.sec.android.inputmethod/.SamsungKeypad
```